# Header line height is off

Tags: bug, design

`.post-form h2` has a super huge line height of 34px, causing weird spacing in the preview when a header wraps:

[image: wrapped header with large line height]

Conversely, the rendered headers inherit `.post-text`'s 17px line height, which causes them to appear unnecessarily cramped when they wrap:

[image: wrapped header with cramped line height]